# Export div to pdf multi-page using kendo throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am creating a web app in which I am using kendo, now I want to convert my div into multi-page pdf file

my code looks like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/@mishoo/ABeSo/2) but the above example works fine, but my code is not working,

here is a look at my code,

```
<button onclick="exportPDF()">Export PDF</button>
<div class="content">
    <div class="page">
        First page
    </div>
    <div class="page new-page">
        Second page
    </div>
    <div class="page new-page">
        Third page
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function exportPDF() {
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM(".content", {
        forcePageBreak: ".new-page"
    }).then(function (group) {
        group.options.set("pdf.margin", "1cm");
        kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "test.pdf");
    });
}
```

And I am getting the below error

> ```
> kendo.all.min.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function
>     at r (kendo.all.min.js:26)
>     at Object._e.saveAs (kendo.all.min.js:26)
>     at kendo.all.min.js:54
>     at kendo.all.min.js:54
>     at i (kendo.all.min.js:54)
>     at i (kendo.all.min.js:54)
>     at kendo.all.min.js:54
>     at XMLHttpRequest.Ue.msie.r.onload (kendo.all.min.js:54)
> ```

how can I solve this problem

Comment: May I know how you include js file?

Comment: js file is in my layout page

Comment: function exportPDF() call before js included or not?

Comment: it is calling properly, I think the problem is related to version

Comment: which version you are using it?

Comment: kendo verion -> 2019.2.514

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206516/discussion-between-jinesh-and-ibrahim-shaikh).